# SQL Server 2008, how much space does this occupy?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I am trying to calculate how much space (Mb) this would occupy. In the database table there is 7 bit columns, 2 tiny int and 1 guid.

Trying to calculate the amount that 16 000 rows would occupies.

My line of thought was that 7 bit columns consume 1 byte, 2 tiny ints consumes 2 bytes and a guid consumes 16 bytes. Total of 19byte for one row in the table? That would mean 304000 bytes for 16 000 rows or ~0.3mbs us that correct? Is there a meta data byte as well?

Comment: Are the columns nullable? I think you use up 1 bit per null-able column too.

Comment: Sorry, no nullable columns. They all have a default of 1 or 0 except the guid thats generated in c#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are [several estimators out there](http://www.google.co.uk/#q=sql+server+table+size+estimator) which take away the donkey work

You have to take into account the Null bitmap which will be 3 bytes in this case + number of rows per page + row header + row version + pointers + all the stuff here:

[Inside the Storage Engine: Anatomy of a record](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/Inside-the-Storage-Engine-Anatomy-of-a-record.aspx)

Edit:

Your 19 bytes of actual data

- has 11 bytes overhead
- total 30 bytes per row
- around 269 rows per page (8096 / 30)
- requires 60 pages (16000 / 269)
- around 490k space (60 x 8192)
- a few KB for the index structure of the primary

Comment: So this page is still pretty accurate even for SQL server 2008 R2?
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827968

Comment: And word about the transaction log?

Comment: I just created such a table as a heap, and it came in at 0.477MB Data, 0.008MB index. Adding a clustered PK against the guid column gives 0.453MB data, 0.016MB index. So the answer is approximately correct :-)